# How is invalid_kwargs attribute being set in Snowflake operator inside an Airflow DAG?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a DAG set with the following operator task:

```
snowflake_op = SnowflakeOperator(
    account='my_snowflake_account.my_region', # not a real account, just for the purpose of demonstrating
    task_id='snowflake_op',
    dag=dag, #the DAG object instantiated 
    sql='SHOW DATABASES',
    warehouse='MY_WAREHOUSE',
    role='USER_ROLE',
    database='MY_DATABASE',
    schema='MY_SCHEMA'
)
```

It runs OK, however there is a unit test DAG Validation which searches for invalid kwargs in the operators. These are just put in an dict called `invalid_kwargs`. The test fails showing with this message:

> AssertionError: ["DAG File: my_dag_file.py, TIER: tier3, DAG: my_dag,
> TASK: snowflake_op, INVALID KWARGS: {'account':
> 'my_snowflake_account.my_region'}"]

I learned that the test fails once the attribute `invalid_kwargs` is found in the task object (the Operator instance), the test has something like this:

```
if hasattr(task, 'invalid_kwargs'):
    failed_tasks.append('DAG File: ' + dag.filepath + ', ' + 'TIER: ' + dag.tier + ', ' + 'DAG: ' + dag_id + ', ' + 'TASK: '
                                           + task.task_id + ', ' + 'INVALID KWARGS: ' + str(task.invalid_kwargs))
```

So upon debugging, I found that the concerned attribute `invalid_kwargs` is set during instantiation of the SnowflakeOperator, but I can't figure out how the argument `'account'` turns out to be invalid. I have even reviewed the base class [BaseOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/958860fcd7c9ecdf60b7ebeef4397b348835c8db/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L206).

When I need to know is what is causing the `invalid_kwargs` to be set. I even tried inheriting the SnowflakeOperator overloading the constructor with an explicit `'account'` argument, so it would not be a kwarg. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you including .snowflakecomputing.com in your account argument?  if so, please remove and test again with just my_snowflake_account.my_region.

Comment: My mistake. The actual value is just snowflake_account.region, I'll correct in the question. But I think the problem is with the attribute `account` itself independently of its value.

Comment: Are you using an Airflow connection? If so, I don't expect you'd need to specify the account here. The way ours is set up, account (and database, warehouse, and region) are specified in the connection's Extra field. (I realize that account should be valid, and omitting account would really just be a workaround.)

Comment: @Pepik Yes it is airflow. What extra field is that? where?

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares In Airflow, you set up connections by going to Admin->Connections. If you edit a connection, the last field is called 'Extra', and that's where we specify account, warehouse, region, and database.

Comment: @Pepik Thanks, but that is not an option for me, because of some restrictions on the admin panel. However I think I can set this property in the JSON config file.

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares, since you don't have access, you might want to have a chat with whomever manages your Airflow instance and make sure that they've configured the connection properly. [Here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/2.2.0/connections/snowflake.html) is the official doc, and [this](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect-Apache-Airflow-to-Snowflake-and-schedule-queries-jobs) has screenshots to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

So I worked around this by creating an inherited class of SnowflakeOperator but not passing the argument to the super constructor,

```
class MySnowflakeOperator(SnowflakeOperator):
    def __init__(self,
        *,
        sql: Any,
        parameters: Optional[dict] = None,
        warehouse: Optional[str] = None,
        database: Optional[str] = None,
        role: Optional[str] = None,
        schema: Optional[str] = None,
        account: Optional[str] = None,
        **kwargs,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__( # the account argument isn't passed to BaseOperator constructor
            sql=sql,
            parameters=parameters,
            warehouse=warehouse,
            database=database,
            role=role,
            schema=schema,
            **kwargs
        )
        self.sql = sql
        self.parameters = parameters
        self.account = account
        self.warehouse = warehouse
        self.database = database
        self.role = role
        self.schema = schema
```

The `account` is taken then passed straight to the hook.

```
def get_hook(self) -> SnowflakeHook:
    return SnowflakeHook(
        account=self.account,
        warehouse=self.warehouse,
        database=self.database,
        role=self.role,
        sql=self.sql,
        schema=self.schema,
    )
```

This seems to avoid the invalid_kwargs property to be set.